# Subquery repeats values

Tags: mysql

I got this query to retrieve total price, average and difference but i think i am inputting the group by or order by incorrect because it shows me all the data i want except it just repeats the same customer name, cellphone and email for every result but the total price, average and difference are all different

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    CellPhone,
    Email,
    TotalPrice,
    AVG(TotalPrice) AS 'Average Total Price',
    TotalPrice - 'Average Total Price' AS 'Difference Total Price'
FROM
    customer,
    (SELECT 
        CID, TotalPrice
    FROM
        orders) AS c
GROUP BY TotalPrice 
ORDER BY FirstName;
```

Comment: It makes no sense to average the column you're grouping by. All the rows will have the same `TotalPrice`, so the average will be the same.

Comment: You need a joining condition between `customer` and `orders`. Otherwise you're creating a cross product between all the customers and all orders.

Comment: You don't say what the desired result should be, but I suspect you should be grouping by `customer.ID`.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to include `TotalPrice` in the results. There are many different values of `TotalPrice`, which one should be returned?

Comment: Please show sample input and the desired results.

Comment: [ Robert | Downey | 646-567-0099 | Rdownjr@gmail.com | 169.90 | 81.779268 | 169.9]
                  [Chris | Evans | 929-543-8766 | ChrisEv@aol.com | 169.90 | 81.779268 | 169.9 ]
this two results the names, phone and email are fixed using group by customer id but the total, average and difference are the same for both when they should have their own unique results

Comment: please edit your question instead of adding details in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67511981/edit

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    c.CellPhone,
    c.Email,
    o.TotalPrice,
    a.AvgPrice AS `Average Total Price`,
    o.TotalPrice - a.AvgPrice AS `Difference Total Price`
FROM customer AS c
JOIN orders AS o ON c.ID = o.CID
JOIN (
    SELECT CID, AVG(TotalPrice) AS AvgPrice
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY CID
) AS a ON a.CID = c.ID
ORDER BY c.FirstName
```

The subquery gets the average totals from all the orders of each customer. This is then joined with the rows for each order so you can get the difference.